# Safely deleting rsnapshot _delete folders

Tags: linux, rsnapshot, rm

I have been using rsnapshot to backup a computer's `/` for approximately a year. The destination drive has filled up unexpectedly quickly within the last week or so, and the rsync command has failed, leading to lots of `_delete.22400` folders created in its root.

Owing to the somewhat unusual configuration of the machine, it transpires that several of these folders contain symlinks to places on `/` that I care *very, very* much about. If I call `rm -r /path/to/rsnapshot_directory`, can I be *absolutely* certain that I won't accidentally nuke the original file on the machine?

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```
$ ls -l /media/disk-1/_delete.27061/localhost/vnmr
lrwxrwxrwx <snip> /media/disk-1/_delete.27061/localhost/vnmr -> /home/vnmrj_4.0_A
$ ls /media/disk-1/_delete.* | wc -w
16
```

I'm afraid that `/bin/rm -r /media/disk-1/_delete*` would delete the target of these links, and not the links themselves. Should I be? (I'm tempted to pull the drive and do it on another computer!)

Comment: Run a `find` command to discover  those symlinks and remove those and then you can be assured your recursive `rm` can't follow them. Or use `find` to execute `rm` , as find does have options that control if symbolic links are followed.

Comment: @HBrujin -- isn't this complicated by the fact that rsnapshot creates hard links? What about something like `find ./ -type l -exec unlink {} \; && rm ./`? As long as one link somewhere else on the fs exists, this...shouldn't break anything, should it?